# AdMob interstitial not showing What is wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am trying to add admob interstitial ads to my app but when I run my app no ad shows up. I just get a message in the logs saying :

`<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @« deviceID » ];`

I'm pretty sure it knows im trying to show an add because of a previous error but it just won't appear.

here is my code( I added a print statement to the first part but it doesn't seem to take it into considiration ):

```
if interstitialad != nil {
            if interstitialad!.isReady {
                interstitialad?.present(fromRootViewController: self)

            }
        }
```

here is the second part of the code ( note both are in ViewDidLoad )

```
if interstitialad != nil {
            if interstitialad!.isReady {
                interstitialad?.present(fromRootViewController: self)
            }
        }


        func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
            let request = GADRequest()
            let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "unit id")
            //request.testDevices = ["iPhone test device ID"]
            //request.testDevices = ["simulator ID"]
            interstitial.delegate = self
            interstitial.load(request)
            return interstitial
        }
        interstitialad = createAndLoadInterstitial()
```

What is wrong with this? 
Thanks !

Comment: What is the error you are getting during initiation and loading?

Comment: @AbilashBNair I don't get any errors, It just doesn't appear, If I don't add the device ID it gives me <Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @« deviceID » ]; in the logs but when I do I Don't get anything.

Comment: Check whether you have entered correct  adUnitID as per AdMob dashboard. Also make sure you have registered your App inside AdMob Id.

Comment: are you using this code in viewDidLoad ?. Interstial Ads take time of atleast 3 seconds to load. call interstitialad?.present(fromRootViewController: self)  after 3 seconds of create interstitial.load(request)

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla yes I am using this code in viewDidLoad. I have waited a long time for it to load ( way more than 3 seconds) , are you saying I need to setup a timer ?

Comment: @AbilashBNair everything looks fine on that side

Comment: I just want to say that present your ad after 3 seconds of createAndLoadInterstitial(). Your Ad must be loaded at the time of presentation

Comment: If it doesn't work then first try to load this test Ad Unit ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla I've tried that, still nothing

Comment: Is test ad is also not working ?

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla yes thats right, test ads aren't working either. Note I edited the question witch might help solving the issue.

Comment: Are you still presenting ad in viewdidload ?

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla yes I am

Comment: Try lo load your ad in viewDidLoad and set a timer 0f 5 seconds and then present Ad check it is working or not. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Ad Interstitial Objective C Working code:

```
- (void)startAdInterstial
{
 self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:FIREBASE_ADMOBID];;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[kGADSimulatorID,@"7b5e0f6aad46c15f1e9ef2e6d3d381b7"];
    
    _interstitial.delegate = self;
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];

}

#pragma mark -  interstitial delegate

- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad
{
    [_interstitial presentFromRootViewController:[APPDELEGATE window].rootViewController];
}

- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)ad didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error during full screen view %@",error);
}


- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    
}
```

Hope this will help you out in some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some code which I used to initiate the AdMob in Objective-c:

AdMobHandler.m file:

//created 320x60 banner and displayed at the bottom of UIView.

**//If your app in development stage then you need to add the device ID or simulator ID which will appear during AdMob Initiation.
  To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ];**

```
- (void)initiateAndLoadAdMob:(UIViewController *)sender
{
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

 GADBannerView  *bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];

    request.testDevices = @[ @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <<Device ID>>",@"xxxxxxx<<Simulator ID>>" ];
    bannerView.adUnitID = FIREBASE_ADMOBID;
    bannerView.rootViewController = (id)self;
    bannerView.delegate = (id<GADBannerViewDelegate>)self;
    senderView = sender.view;
     bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, senderView.frame.size.height - bannerHeight, senderView.frame.size.width, bannerHeight);
    [senderView addSubview:bannerView];


}
```

If you able to understand and change code to Swift will gives you some idea and solve your above issue. Let me know if you have any queries for above code.

For more details check this below link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/interstitial

Comment: Hes trying to display a `GADInterstitial` not a `GADBannerView`.

Answer (score 1):

You said you're trying to present your `GADInterstitial` in your `viewDidLoad`. This is not when you should be presenting your `GADInterstitial`. You need to give the `GADInterstitial` time to load the ad. Presenting an ad in your `viewDidLoad` is also against the AdMob TOS. You should be presenting the `GADInterstitial` during a transition/action in your application. You should also implement the `GADInterstitial` delegate methods so you know why the ad is failing to load, when it has actually loaded, and when the user has dismissed the ad so you can continue to transition them in your application.

- [Disallowed interstitial implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287)
- [GADInterstitial Ad Events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/ad-events)