# How to make the interstitial ads load and appear on the app's UI? no respond in Xcode10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-mobile-ads

I'm trying to load an interstitial ad in my app by integrating Firebase. when I click on "IBAction button" I am supposed to get an advertisement. But I get no response at all and don't see any ads on the screen.

Xcode console shows the below message:
1-[I-ACS037005] Unable to fetch effective App ID from identity
2- You are currently using version 7.37.0 of the SDK. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest features and bug fixes. The latest SDK can be downloaded from...etc

and this is my code:-

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

@IBAction func rewardedAdBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "/6499/example/interstitial")
    let request = GADRequest()
    //request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID, "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ]

    interstitial.load(request)
}
```

I added two helpful functions the first one got "printed" but the second isn't !!

```
    /// Tells the delegate an ad request succeeded.
func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    print("interstitialDidReceiveAd")
}


/// Tells the delegate that an interstitial will be presented.
func interstitialWillPresentScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
    print("interstitialWillPresentScreen")
}
```

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050313/admob-interstitial-not-showing-what-is-wrong

Comment: thanks, but it didn't help banner ads load fine but interstitial not loading

Comment: Can you confirm that you have indeed checked and followed the implementation 'rules' as described in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099567/3419541 ?
NB. The Xcode log message "[I-ACS037005] Unable to fetch effective App ID from identity" might be unrelated. (I am seeing a banner in my app, and yet still get that exact log message using Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK 7.44.0)